# htaccess passing params wth POST mechanism

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

Got 2 htaccess questions, hopefully you could help me out:

1) Why do these commands don't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/Bing$ http://$1 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/Bing\/(.*)$ http://$1/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

while these do work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/Bing$ http://www.myDomain.com [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/Bing\/(.*)$ http://www.myDomain.com /$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

2) I want to use htaccess for the following manipulation:

when

current url =POST http://www.myDomain.com/

HTTP_REFERER = //www.myDomain.com/3

{Param2= x (some const value)}

will be silently converted to

POST (not GET!)  http://www.myDomain.com/Myservice.asmx/Foo

{Param1 = 3, Param2= x (stays the same as before manipulation)}

Thanks in advance to any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. RewriteRule does not ever get the host. Just the path, you will have to use RewriteCond with HTTP_HOST to do anything with the host.
2. You can preserve post data by adding another directive along with your NC, R i.e. P, which stands for preserving post data.